# Textbox with same ID inside Gridview Validation

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview with 100 Textboxes one below the other. I want to validate it as Atleast One textbox should be filled, otherwise Save button should not work and Ask for user to enter atleast one textbox.  Is there any ways to do this?In my case, Gridview Textboxes Have same id as 'txtempcode'.

I'm using vb.net with SQl database as backend.

Here is my Design code

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" style="margin-left: 23px" Width="420px" CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"  >
               <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
             <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField Headertext="Sr No." DataField="Row_No"  />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee Code">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtEmpcode" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TxtId_TextChanged" AutoPostBack ="true"   ></asp:TextBox>
             
             </Columns>
             
         </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What language and platform are you using? Could you show us a [mcve]? We have no idea if this is Android, XAML, HTML, or any of a dozen other UI tools. Please edit your question to include this information, so we know what you're dealing with here; we can't look over your shoulder at your code.

Comment: To Shotgun Ninja's point, even with the edit, you should probably add ASP.NET and VB.NET, at a minimum, as tags.

Answer (score 0):

In your Save button's click event:

```
Dim bValueFound as Boolean = False

for each i as listitem in GridView2.items
  try
    if DirectCast(i.findControl("TxtEmpcode"), TextBox).text > "" then           
      bValueFound = True
      exit for
    end if      
  catch
    'Hopfully just Header
  end try
next

If bValueFound then 
  'Do Save Button Tasks
else 
  'Remind user to fill something in?
End If
```

You may want to do more than just **...text > ""** but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: That Try/Catch is a bit of a lazy solution.  You should probably check whether i.itemtype is Header instead.